# Dynamically change level hierarchy in plotly sunburst chart

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I've managed to create a plotly sunburst chart and to change the hierarchy of the levels via dropdown during "runtime" by using predefined hierarchys and previously generating the needed datasets.

That's okay for small hierarchies and small amounts of data. For larger hierarchies and large amounts of data it doesn't seem rational to me to generate all possible or interesting configurations and to generate all needed datasets previously.

Is there a way to add something like a dropdown for each hierarchy and to let the user choose what should be on level 1, level 2, level 3, ... and then just reorganize the given dataset to display the chosen hierarchy?

Usually i would try to puzzle some GUI together and just calculate the new data in the background but since the chart opens in my browser and takes quite some time to compute with larger datasets I'm not quite sure how to solve this.
[image]

```py
df = px.data.tips()

# construct figures for multiple hierarchies
figs = {
    c: px.sunburst(df, path=c, values="tip")
    for c in [tuple(["day", "time", "sex"]), tuple(["time", "day", "sex"])]
}

# choose a hierarchy that becomes the figure
fig = figs[("day", "time", "sex")]

# now build menus, that use parameters that have been pre-built using plotly express
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": str(c),
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "labels": [figs[c].data[0].labels],
                            "parents": [figs[c].data[0].parents],
                            "values": [figs[c].data[0].values],
                            "ids": [figs[c].data[0].ids],
                            "hovertemplate": figs[c].data[0].hovertemplate,
                        }
                    ],
                }
                for c in figs.keys()
            ]
        }
    ]
)

# display chart
fig.show()
```

Comment: I think the issue is that if you have multiple dropdowns in plotly, they can't communicate with each other: one dropdown won't "know" what the other dropdown has selected, and therefore you can't have more than one dropdown that changes how the sunburst is constructed. however, `plotly-dash` supports this functionality because of `callbacks` so such a solution would work i believe

Comment: That's exactly the way. Thanks!